# Deploying Vue/Nuxt app to Firebase as Universal App with SSR

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy my Universal Nuxt.js app to Firebase. All information on doing this appears to be out-dated, and I'm not able to get it fully working.

SSR appears to work, along with static assets being hosted. Middleware though, for example, its only being executed on the client - and not on the server (such as when it is first loaded through SSR) when it is deployed on firebase with firebase functions/hosting (or using `firebase serve`).

I have the following project structure:

```
project
└─ /functions (firebase functions including `nuxt/` built files)
└─ /src (nuxt app, using `create-nuxt-app` starter template)
└─ /public (includes static files and built nuxt client files)
└─ firebase.json
```

in `src/nuxt.config.js` set the build options

```
mode: 'universal',
...
buildDir: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '.nuxt' : '../functions/nuxt',
build: {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/public/' : '/',
  extractCSS: true,

  ...
}
```

in `functions/package.json` set to use node v8

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
},
...
```

and the following to `functions/index.js`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

// Set Nuxt.js options
const config = {
  dev: false,
  buildDir: 'nuxt',
  build: {
    publicPath: '/'
  },
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600')
  nuxt.renderRoute('/')
    .then(result => {
      res.send(result.html)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.send(e)
    })
}
app.get('*', handleRequest)
exports.nuxtapp = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

in `firebase.json` instruct firebase to use the function

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "nuxtapp"
  }
]
```

I've also added all dependencies from `src/package.json` to `functions/package.json`.

On `npm run build` in `src` folder, the built Nuxt client files (`firebase/nuxt/dist/client/*`) and the app's static files (`src/static/*`) are being copied into the `public` folder before being deployed (for firebase static hosting and CDN).

Using this setup, static assets hosting and SSR appears to work when deployed on Firebase, but the `middleware/asyncData/nuxtServerInit/etc` is not being executed when it is server side rendered using the Firebase function.

The middleware for example works as expected on both server/client when on dev mode locally (`npm run dev`).

What am I missing or doing wrong to get this working when deployed on Firebase?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your repo public so I can take a look? I need more information to be able to help. What happens when you hit with a GET request to the firebase function directly

Comment: I found this tutorial, it may help you: https://dev.to/kiritchoukc/deploy-nuxt-on-firebase-4ad8

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I'm facing same issue with firebase cloud functions on "nuxtServerInit/middleware" but no issue with "asyncData". Did you solve it?

Comment: I never did, but within a week I'll be attempting to finish the project. I think I'll be using https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/appengine-deployment though

Comment: It's the first time I've tried to deploy an app, so I'm not an expert, but something I did read is cold start calls to functions for ssr can take a while, which isn't good for SEO, and also firebase functions may not be very economical for these compute times.

Comment: Or maybe https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-cloud-run https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run. More docs and services available since I last tried I think

Comment: I've actually managed to make it work, to avoid cold start calls I've reduced to minimum by using a service like "uptimeRobot" that pings my website every 6/7mins. I'm quite happy with the result.

Comment: @Valentin thanks for sharing this tutorial, looks very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Nuxt 2.12> your nuxt.config.js file does not need to have the "mode" attribute. Just use target: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-target/ (Static also works with SSR)

Your middleware dir is used to place middlewares that you want to execute in client and SSR every page that user visits. But if you are looking for a server middleware that works with cloud functions you can use Nuxt server middlewares: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/

(Check this doc for detailed information about middlewares vs server middlewares)